# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@types/svgo'

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, svgo

I have installed types for svgo using

`yarn add @types/svgo`.

In the file where I want to use svgo I write:

`import SVGO from 'svgo';`

From there I can comfortably inspect types by going to definition from svgo.

But when I runt `yarn install` or similar commands in the console I get:

```
ERROR in dll renderer
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@types/svgo' in 'C:\[projectfolder]'
 @ dll renderer renderer[2]
error Command failed with exit code 2
```

It is an Electron project recently started from the electron-react-boilerplate.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. The solution is to move `@types/*` to `devDependencies` rather than keep them in `dependencies` in `package.json`.

If you have a new project then you should use [yard add](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add) with `--dev` flag, i.e. `yarn add --dev @types/svgo`.

Comment: moving `@types/*` to `devDependencies` saved the day. Thanks!